# How to prevent a backBarButton's title disappear when add a Inline Search Bar to Navigation Bar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

#### Context

We have an existing project which is build in UIKit, and now I want to have a new view created in SwiftUI with Search Bar stay on the navigation bar.

Which search bar is **INLINE** with the `backBarButtonItem`, so obviously modifier `searchable` cannot fulfill my requirement.

The simplify flow can be simplify like this
[image]

#### Issue

But when I try to do a proof of concept. The code will be at the last section of this question.

I found out that after pushing out the title of `backBarButtonItem` is shown at the first moment then disappear when the search bar added. Which is really bad in experience.

[image]

#### My Question

1. Is there any way to fix?
2. and why it is behavior like that?

##### [Update]

Thanks for Sweeper 's hint, when I tried to change the `barButtonTitle` to a shorter string, the text will stay there:

```swift
// In ViewController's viewDidLoad
navigationItem.backButtonTitle = "A"
```

[image: shorter backButtonTitle]

Therefore, the new question becoming like

- How to higher backBarButtonItem 's compress resistance
- How to stop the backButtonTitle from hidden

I tried to search with my new question but didn't get any useful solution. If it's hard to do it either with SwiftUI and UIKit, I can considering and persuade our designer to not show the `backButtonTitle`.

#### Code

##### ViewController in UIKit

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        title = "Demo"

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(didSelectCancel(sender:)))
    }

    @objc func didSelectCancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: MyView())
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(hostingController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

##### MyView in SwiftUI

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                SearchBar(text: .constant("test"), placeholder: "test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### SearchBar

Since SwiftUI doesn't provide stand alone SearchBar, so I grab one from article [Creating a search bar for SwiftUI](https://axelhodler.medium.com/creating-a-search-bar-for-swiftui-e216fe8c8c7f) and using it in my PoC

```swift
struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.placeholder = placeholder
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you just want `self.navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""` before pushing the SwiftUI view.

Comment: Not really what I want but yeah it's a good start to debug this. And I found out the reason why `backButtonTitle` got hidden is because the title length. It stays there when I changed it to a single character. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: The question seems becoming how to higher the compression resistance of `backBarButtonItem` so far I haven't found any way to do it but I will update my original question.